# Icon images with node title

Tags: nodes, media

I'm using Drupal 7, and I want to put specific icons close to node titles. How can I do this?

This is how I want the node titles to appear.

[image: screenshots]

Comment: Could you perhaps..umm..make this a question?

Comment: What @Chapabu said. `questionMark != question` I'm afraid.

Comment: plus, what have you tried that didn't work for you?

Comment: Never tried any method because i don't know how its solve. So, i asked to you.

Comment: This question is too broad. What is the criteria you want to use to add icons to node titles? If you just want to add the same icon to every node title, that is a thing; if you want to add different icons, you need to explain which criteria you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS to theme your `<h1>` tag on the node page to include this image as a background image, similar to the method for custom bullets on a `<li>` element.

If different icons represent different node types, then use Drupal's default CSS selectors to specify which CSS elements you need to target for that page.

For example, 'weather content type' might use the following CSS selectors.

```
body.node-weather #node h1 { my background image }
```